# How to use the focus property in Scenebuilder?

Tags: css, fxml, scenebuilder

I am making a GUI in scenebuilder, and I want to add some CSS to it. Is there a way to add the focus property to a textfield in directly in the scenebuilder app?

So how to do the following in scenebuilder?
Example:

```
input:focus{
background-color: blue;}
```